# git show does not understand relative file names

Tags: shell, git, root-filesystem, git-log

I am using git to version control config files on my system. I have git root at the root of my filesystem `/`, and I control `/etc` and `/root`.

When I am in `/root` and do: `git log .zshrc`, it shows me commit history. I want to display the contents of `.zshrc` for particular commit:

```
# git show a100e3515779a900509b52230d449a6446fa110b:.zshrc     
fatal: Path 'root/.zshrc' exists, but not '.zshrc'.
Did you mean 'a100e3515779a900509b52230d449a6446fa110b:root/.zshrc' aka 
'a100e3515779a900509b52230d449a6446fa110b:./.zshrc'?

# git show a100e3515779a900509b52230d449a6446fa110b:/root/.zshrc
fatal: Path '/root/.zshrc' exists on disk, but not in 

# git show a100e3515779a900509b52230d449a6446fa110b:root/.zshrc

# git show a100e3515779a900509b52230d449a6446fa110b:./.zshrc
```

only the last 2 commands works. Why do `.zshrc` and `/root/.zshrc` not work, and why do I have to use the least convenient notation such as `./.zshrc` ?

Is there some configuration option that I can change, so that git understands `.zshrc` and `/root/.zshrc` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `<rev>:<path>` notation, the path is relative to the tree-ish object itself, not to the current directory, unless it starts with `./` or `../`. In both cases absolute paths (`…:/…`) aren’t supported, only relative paths.

```
git show a100e3515779a900509b52230d449a6446fa110b:.zshrc
```

means “find the a100e3515779a900509b52230d449a6446fa110b object, and inside that object, show me the `.zshrc` file”. Think of a100e3515779a900509b52230d449a6446fa110b as an archive of sorts; it exists independently of your current directory, and has no notion of your current directory.

As far as I’m aware there’s no configuration option you can change to get `git show` to understand `.zshrc` as `./.zshrc` in this context.

See [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for details.